# Converting timestamp on server gives different result in PHP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, time, timezone, timestamp

Consider this. On my server, I convert a (UTC/GMT) timestring like this:

```
strtotime('Fri Feb 18 21:08:38 +0000 2011')
```

My server returns

```
1298063318
```

This is correct, since all [unix](http://www.gaijin.at/olsutc.php) [timestamp](http://www.4webhelp.net/us/timestamp.php?action=stamp&stamp=1298063318&timezone=0) [converters](http://www.epochconverter.com/) that I tested, return the same. And vice versa, if I insert not the date but the timestamp, I get returned the timestring as given above. **But** if I convert the timestamp on my server:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1298063318);
```

I get back a different date than expected (being 'Fri Feb 18 21:08:38 +0000 2011'):

```
2011-02-18 22:08:38
```

So it's off an hour. This is probably because my servers timezone is set at Europe/Paris, and it thus translates the timestamp into UTC/GTM + 1. But MySQL, ran on the same server and having the same timezone, gives me back another result:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1298063318) = 2011-02-18 22:08:15
```

In other words, it is off 18 seconds. Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MySQL, a [leap second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) correction is used for the date functions ([MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-leap-seconds.html)). For PHP date functions, leap seconds are not taken into account. For that reason, you get now a 24 seconds difference.

You can try the following to solve your problem: http://pumka.net/2010/10/24/why-mysql-timestamp-is-24-seconds-different-from-php/

PS. 38 - 15 = 23

Comment: Would upvote twice if possible, just for the PS xD How did I miscalculate?! Must be the heavy breakfast.